# Kivy QPython app on Android Moto G phone - no log output

Tags: android, kivy, qpython

I'm having some trouble with my Kivy apps when run from the QPython launcher.

If I run the standard pong example, I don't see any output.

This used to work.
So, I suspect that QPython, or Kivy has taken an 'upgrade' which has broken something.

In the past I would be able to swipe down to see the log output icon.
But, now that's no longer there.
Well done QPython, Kivy !!!!

So, what's changed?
And, how am I supposed to check program log output to see why it no longer runs?

Regards

Nick

Answer (score 1):

As I replied to Zaphod's post on the missing log before my answer was removed: I've made an issue on qpython's github about that problem and the dev have answered. The "no log information" is  a bug and he should remove it in the next update. As a temporary fix, I reroute my stdout and stderr to .run.log:

```
import sys
f=open('.run.log','w') 
f.close()
sys.stdout=open('.run.log','a') 
sys.stderr=open('.run.log','a')
```

Laurent

Comment: Hi Laurent, OK, cool, that's got the log working again, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about qpython's log stuff, but you can see the kivy log output by viewing the logcat stream, e.g. from an attached computer (with developer mode enabled) using `adb logcat`.

This has always been possible and is the standard way to view the log output with kivy (and with android in general). It sounds like your direct problem relates to a change in qpython.

Comment: OK, logcat is useful, never come across that before.

Comment: Now that I have that working, I can't tell if there is info in there to pinpoint my problem, but these two lines don't look good: I/python  (17701): [CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
I/python  (17701): pygame - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_keyboard_height'

Comment: I've run the same simple app on my Android powered Nexus 7. And it runs OK on there. The Moto G is running kivy 1.9.0 and the Nexus is running Kivy 1.7.2 . So I suspect that there is some incompatibility in an upgrade taken by my Moto G.

Comment: And, for info, the Moto G has Python v2.7.2 . I think that's the version of QPython that I installed when I got the phone about 9 months ago. So, maybe Kivy has taken an upgrade but QPython hasn't ?!?!

Comment: Oh, no, maybe not, I see this in logcat: I/python  (17701): [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Jul 20 2015, 22:37:44)

Comment: The keyboard height stuff appeared more recently than 1.7.2 (which is really old).

Comment: It sounds like you could be using a newer version of kivy, but an older version of the python-for-android backend (specifically the android module).

Comment: I can't upgrade to QPython3 yet because there is no kivy support in there.

Comment: This isn't about qpython3, it's about your kivy version not being compatible (probably) with the version of the android module.

Comment: Inclement <-- what do you mean by "the android module" ? Do you mean the PY4A (Python for Android) ?

Comment: Kivy's python-for-android includes a module named 'android' providing access to some platform-specific features. It is included automatically in apks built with kivy's build tools, and must also be included with qpython.