# How to display error occurred in script?

Tags: kivy, qpython

I think my question is already asked, but I didn't find any topic about that.
When I try somme script with kivy, I have sometimes errors (such as undeclared variable, bad indentation...), but Qpython don't display them.
I lunch kivy with:
"#qpy:kivy"
and consequently, there is no console. A log is however present, but it's empty.
Is there a way to remedy this ?
Should I add a line to display error ?

Thanks

Simon

PS: The "print" command is also useful, but not working (no console). I think it's the same problem.

Comment: I answered this question in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852534/kivy-qpython-app-on-android-moto-g-phone-no-log-output

Laurent

Comment: OK, thank you, I didn't see it, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The newest 1.2.0 version had fixed this blank log issue.